# What's the shortcut for "Hide or show the Utilities" pane in Xcode4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xcode4

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot #1]

What's the name and its shortcut key of the 3rd button in `View` group? (2nd button is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>, and first is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>)

Comment: because some men just want to watch the world burn

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>. You can find it in the View -> Utilities menu.

Comment: Can I override shortcut key for this? I can't find the setting in preference!!

Answer (score -7):

view.backgroundColor = .grayColor()